# Prevent MySql from mangling queries by casting string to int

Tags: mysql

On one of my tables I have an auto incrementing ID field. It also has another field (richter_code) with a unique constraint but, over the seasons, this field can change - that's why I'm not using it as the primary key.

In my program's code, I have a load function. First thing it does is check the richter_code field for the search parameter. If it doesn't return anything, it then goes on to search the on the ID field for the same parameter.

The problem is that it seems to truncate the value as soon as it encounters an alpha character. So I'm getting complete garbage from my query. See screenshot for example.
Can I prevent mysql from changing the query?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't know about autocasting and truncation, but try with `SELECT * FROM cloths WHERE CAST(id AS VARCHAR) = "3R100C"`

Comment: I can't cast it to varchar. Syntax error :(

Comment: Does the autoincremented `Id` column have any business meaning? Why would the progran even try to use it for a search?

Comment: You can, I just suggested the wrong type (I didn't check [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)). Replace `VARCHAR` with `CHAR` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gotta love MySql ;)

I searched Stack Overflow for a MySql equivalent to some `isnumeric` function, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql).

This rather convoluted WHERE clause would return the expected 0 rows:

```
where Id = case when concat('','3R100C'*1) = '3R100C' then '3R100C' else null end
```

The idea is to only match the parameter against `Id` *when it is a valid numeric value*. Hope it helps!

---

I'd create an actual `isinteger` function to abstract away this sheer madness:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `isinteger`(v varchar(255)) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN

    RETURN CASE WHEN CONCAT('', v * 1) = v THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

END
```

---

That said I don't think it's right to use an auto-incremented `Id` field as a search-fallback column - this ID is your table's primary key, its meaning belongs strictly on the database side, no program should ever care about it, even less a program's user.

Comment: Note that this function will return 0 in the event of an integer overflow.. which isn't technically wrong ;)

Comment: I think you could use `else null` instead of `else -1`

Comment: I'd be worried by the performance of calling a custom function (performance penalty that, if any, I don't know). A benchmark of both solutions would be interesting.

Comment: @ypercube good point, edited ;)

Comment: Besides the *1 trick, this might also work: `WHEN CAST(CAST('3R100C' AS int) AS char) = '3R100C'`

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that MySQL is doing an implicit conversion from the string to an int when doing the comparison....

```
SELECT * FROM cloths WHERE id = "3R100C"
```

making the conversion explicit, this is what MySQL is doing:

```
SELECT * FROM cloths WHERE id = CAST("3R100C" as int)
```

Instead, what you want to do is cast the id to a string, and compare that way. The solution is simply to:

```
SELECT * FROM cloths WHERE CAST (id as varchar(10)) = "3R100C"
```

That will remove any need for the integer handling/parsing on the string side.

Comment: This would be correct but rather horrible for performance.

Comment: @ypercube - you're right, it will require an index-scan for all records. The alternative is to do the string-is-integer check, and cast it if it is, and then do the index lookup with that. Depending on the plan, it may well do the cast and check even for values that have non-digit content. Actual testing in the actual environment will be important.