# Function is accepting varchar when input is set to INT

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a function that is suppose to have INT as input. However, when I pass any string, the input is accepted.

Why does the function not error out because of the input not matching the input type?

This is the function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS erbaccess.canAdminIRB;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION erbaccess.canAdminIRB(_userID int) RETURNS int

BEGIN

set @canPerformAction = 0;

if (select count(*)
    from erbaccess.usersVsGroupsVsActions
    where (actionCode in ('ADMSYS', 'ADDIRB')   
            or privilegeGroupCode  in ('SYS', 'REG')    
    and userID = _userID) > 0 then

    set @canPerformAction = 1;
end if;

RETURN @canPerformAction;

END $$
```

The `RETURN` for `@canPerformAction` is also returned as 1, when it should be 0. IF I run just the if statement outside of this function with a fake username (not `INT`, but `VARCHAR`) then the return is 0.

Comment: MySQL is performing an  [implicit conversion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/89760/110455) between char and int. Have a look at [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

> The server handles the data type of a routine parameter, local
> routine variable created with DECLARE, or function return value as
> follows:
>
> - Assignments are checked for data type mismatches and overflow.
>   Conversion and overflow problems result in warnings, or errors in
>   strict SQL mode.

...

> MySQL stores the sql_mode system variable setting in effect when a
> routine is created or altered, and always executes the routine with
> this setting in force, regardless of the current server SQL mode when
> the routine begins executing.
>
> The switch from the SQL mode of the invoker to that of the routine
> occurs after evaluation of arguments and assignment of the resulting
> values to routine parameters. If you define a routine in strict SQL
> mode but invoke it in nonstrict mode, assignment of arguments to
> routine parameters does not take place in strict mode. If you require
> that expressions passed to a routine be assigned in strict SQL mode,
> you should invoke the routine with strict mode in effect.

So you should call your function in SQL strict mode.
See [the docs on how to enable strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) per session or globally at the server level by setting a global variable dynamically or at startup in a config file.

---

Consider an example (MySQL 5.7)

```
create function foobar(myint int) returns int return myint;

set sql_mode = '';
select foobar('10AA');

-- returns 10

set sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
select foobar('10AA');

-- raises an error "[01000][1265] Data truncated for column 'myint' at row 1"
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example to demonstrate the concept.

Answer (score 3):

This is how MySQL liberally performs implicit type conversion. Seeing that the function wants an integer parameter, the server tries to convert whatever you supply (a character string) into an integer. If the string only contains digits, the conversion is trivial. If the string contains digits first and then some non-digits, those latter are truncated at the first non-digit, and the remainder is converted to an integer. If the string *begins* with non-digits, it is converted to a 0.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9491102536dc0374f1daf300dbe8b6b2)

Comment: That's some wild liberty.... Do you know if there is a way to force MySQL to raise an error instead of truncating and zeroing?

Comment: This behaviour is not configurable, as far as I know.