# How to change an incorrect datatype for a birth date field from VARCHAR to DATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, datatypes, date, varchar

I made a mistake when creating my users table with a birthdate field and instead of putting the DATE datatype, I put a VARCHAR!

So now my users table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
(
  id INT    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  birthdate VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and it is populated as follows (sample):

```
INSERT INTO users (id, birthdate) VALUES
  (1,'1991-01-23'),
  (2,'yyyy-01-23'),
  (3,'1991-mm-23'),
  (4,'1991-01-dd'),
  (5,''),
  (6,'1991-01-d3'),
  (7,'1983-05-23'),
  (8,'1991-0m-23'),
  (9,'19yy-01-23'),
  (10,'y991-01-23');
```

Now I want to update every incorrect birthdate to NULL, **or** set a default value like 2020-01-01. see my sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/636bd3/2).

Comment: Please be much more than doubly sure what you're doing when changing date formats, not only because YYYY-01-01 would be an extremely dangerous example in itself, let alone as a default. 

Please first research what revisions your chosen tools have gone through, in stunningly boring detail.

I beg this because I've literally seen DB admins fall to the floor in tears over details of updating dates.

Of course their fears are unlikely to apply to you and how safe is "unlikely"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used dbfiddle.uk (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ba4767e7f4a785036ead66e3af423af3)) for this as opposed to sqlfiddle.com - more servers and it's kept up to date better.

So, what I did was the following (the setup is as per your [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/636bd3/2)):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  birthdate varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

populate:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, birthdate) VALUES
  (1,'1991-01-23'),
  (2,'yyyy-01-23'),
  (3,'1991-mm-23'),
  (4,'1991-01-dd'),
  (5,''),
  (6,'1991-01-d3'),
  (7,'1983-05-23'),
  (8,'1991-0m-23'),
  (9,'19yy-01-23'),
  (10,'y991-01-23');
```

Add a column to hold valid values:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD new_bdate DATE;  -- add column to hold valid values
```

Note that the new field is nullable. It has to be, unless you want to put in some default like 01/01/1900 or '0000-00-00' or '2020-01-01' - I would (strongly) advise against this! It confuses the optimiser when it's figuring out the PLAN and `NULL` is perfectly valid when your datum isn't known!

You mention in comments that trying to use '0000-00-00' as a default fails. This is because the `sql_mode` contains `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` - this is enabled by default in MySQL 5.7 (see the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)) - it is further discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292628/1292-incorrect-date-value-0000-00-00) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime/36374690#36374690) (and accompanying links & comments). From the MySQL docco:

> Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid
> date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and
> inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is
> not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as
> well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted
> and inserts produce a warning.

So, now we alter the `birthdate` field to accept `NULL`s - this is important later when the "cleaning up" is done:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY birthdate VARCHAR (200) NULL;  
-- make birthdate nullable
-- this is important for the STR_TO_DATE function.
```

I also make the original `birthdate` field nullable. If this isn't done, then the first `UPDATE` fails in the `TRANSACTION` below:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE users SET  birthdate = NULL
WHERE birthdate REGEXP '[a-zA-Z/]' OR birthdate = '';
UPDATE users SET new_bdate = birthdate WHERE birthdate IS NOT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

It's important to do both DML steps/queries within the one transaction to avoid any updates between steps - although I imagine that you can do this at a quiet time - or you could [lock the tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) for the duration of your changes.

- Explanation of the regular expression:
  [a-z] means match all characters in the range [a, b, c... x, y, z], and the `A-Z` means the same for capitals. The `/` character will match the slash - can be used in dates, but is not valid for MySQL dates.

Now, we cleanup;

```
ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN new_bdate;
```

Finally, we check our results:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

Result:

```
id  birthdate
1   1991-01-23
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   NULL
5   NULL
6   NULL
7   1983-05-23
8   NULL
9   NULL
10  NULL
10 rows
```

So, now we have a column with the correct datatype and the correct values (where these are known).

Your problem demonstrates the general importance of **never** allowing the entry of free text in an application. If at **all** possible, users should be obliged to choose from drop-downs and ensure the NOT NULL constraint from the get-go!

Also, it shows the importance of choosing the correct datatype from day one! Your database is your last bastion of defence for your data, so ensure that anything that's entered is valid **from the start** - you will avoid issues like this one down the line!

### Edit:

Following comments by the OP, in particular with respect to a date entered into the `VARCHAR` field as `YYYY/mm/dd` (i.e. separator `/` instead of `-`` - @Akina's (elegant) REGEXP [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/288881/34007) can be modified as follows (after adding suitable dates - see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0e37b5ee45b46dd12beee203bf6a74bc)).

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `birthdate`) VALUES 
  (11, '1993/03/20'),
  (12, '2000/09/25');
  (13, '2015.06.30'),
  (14, '2015_04_15');
```

Note the use of the slash (`/`), dot (`.`) or underscore (`_`) characters as separators for the different date  subfields.

SQL:

```
UPDATE users
SET DOB = 
        STR_TO_DATE
        (
          CONCAT
          (
            SUBSTRING(birthdate, 1, 4),
            '-',
            SUBSTRING(birthdate, 6, 2),
            '-',
            SUBSTRING(birthdate, 9, 2)
          ), '%Y-%m-%d'
        )
WHERE birthdate REGEXP '[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}';
```

Result (snipped for brevity):

```
id   birthdate  DOB
...
...
10  y991-01-23  NULL    
11  1993/03/20  1993-03-20
12  2000/09/25  2000-09-25
13  2015.06.30  2015-06-30
14  2015_04_15  2015-04-15
14 rows
```

This is slightly modifed from @Akina's answer - it uses the dot ('.') in the regular expression - the dot being a [regular expression metacharacter](https://help.relativity.com/9.3/Content/Relativity/Regular_expressions/Regular_expression_metacharacters.htm#:%7E:text=Metacharacters%20are%20the%20building%20blocks,character%20with%20a%20literal%20meaning.) (or "special" character) which is a wild-card that can stand for any single (i.e. one and only one) character.

So any year followed by any single character followed by any month by any single character by any day will match - this will cover valid ISO dates (using the hyphen (`-`) or other possible separators , i.e. the underscore or the literal dot character.  The date regexp is somewhat simplified - real ones for dates can be [**much** more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143070/javascript-regex-iso-datetime)!

I had a really tricky time extracting the date from the string. I used the MySQL (non-standard - *quelle surprise!*) string concatenation operator (the plus (`+`)) sign and it started **adding** (i.e. numerically) the year number and the month number. The same thing happened with the MySQL version of the (standard SQL) double-pipe (`||`) operator. It was only when I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89813/34007) that I managed to get to the final working `CONCAT` solution!

As my last link says, `"ya gotta  love MySQL`" - that was not the first emotion which came to me... Yet another reason why I evangalise for PostgreSQL on this forum!

To set your birthdate field to a default of 2020-01-01 (not advised... see above), use the code in @Akina's [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/288876/how-to-remove-update-incorrect-date-format-from-birthdate-field?answertab=oldest#comment564898_288881):

```
SET DOB = 
  CASE 
    WHEN birthdate REGEXP {pattern 1} 
      THEN {expression 1} 
    WHEN {pattern 2} THEN {expression 2} ... ELSE NULL END
```

like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET DOB = 
  CASE 
    WHEN birthdate REGEXP '[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}'
      THEN 
        STR_TO_DATE
        (
          CONCAT
          (
            SUBSTRING(birthdate, 1, 4),
            '-',
            SUBSTRING(birthdate, 6, 2),
            '-',
            SUBSTRING(birthdate, 9, 2)
          ), '%Y-%m-%d'
        )   
      ELSE '2020-01-01'
    END;
```

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02dba7d9ee896c308f9b481c2e957ec2) for the fiddle. +1 for an interesting first question which looked (deceptively) easy but which got me thinking - and welcome to the forum!

Comment: i got an error says incorrect date value '0000-00-00' for column new_bdate

Comment: first i made both fields nullable then I created a procedure to store my transaction then copy pasted your transaction and then call procedure and then error appears 
#1292 - incorrect date value '0000-00-00' for column new_bdate at row im using phpmyadmin

Comment: i got another finding that other date format was inserted to the table. so using the current code it gives an error incorrect date value '08/10/1992'

Comment: I accept this as an answer because of how you put explanations to each code you put. I'm new in this fields , thank you..

Answer (score 4):

```sql
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN DOB DATE;

UPDATE users
    SET DOB = STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    WHERE birthdate REGEXP '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=96c9978ccc667b9289cb3b7b223f28d7

Comment: +1 for an elegant answer - much more elegant than my original one! Validating dates using regular expressions can become very complex - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143070/javascript-regex-iso-datetime). See my answer for my adaptation following comments by OP - do you know of a one-pass solution?

Comment: @Vérace Yes, the query may be more complex, like `SET DOB = CASE WHEN birthdate REGEXP {pattern 1} THEN {expression 1} WHEN {pattern 2} THEN {expression 2} ... ELSE NULL END`.

Comment: I tweaked your answer slightly - I used dot (`.`) as the separator in the REGEXP - this will convert correct (ISO) date strings (i.e. with a hyphen (`-`) and any other date field separators that the end-users may have contrived to input!